# Ruby 1.8.7 Array of symbols raising TypeError: Symbol as array index

Tags: ruby, symbols, ruby-1.8.7

I recently created a [pull request for a gem](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml/pull/454) which is building on travis against quite old ruby versions for backward compatibility.

In my commit I wanted to introduce a whitelist on some method options passed as an hash parameter.

In Rails with a recent ruby version it would look like:

```
MY_WHITELIST = %i(a b c)
def my_method(options={})
  @options = options.slice(*MY_WHITELIST)
end
```

In order to grant backward compatibility in a standalone gem, I provided a solution like:

```
MY_WHITELIST = [:a, :b, :c]
def my_method(options={})
  @options = options.select { |k, _| MY_WHITELIST.include?(k) }
end
```

This pass for ruby `1.9.3` but raise the following exception for `1.8.7`:

```
TypeError: Symbol as array index
```

According to the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html), this way to initialise an array should be accepted.

Have you ever experienced with use? What would you suggest?

Comment: i think the problem it's on the `select.options...` call. Why don't you try with `inject` instead? like `options.inject([]) { |memo, (k, v)| memo << { :k  => v } if MY_WHITELIST.include?(k); memo }`

Comment: thansk @mr_sudaca Now I tried `Hash[options.to_a.select { |k, _| MY_WHITELIST.include?(k) }]` and I am waiting for the ci

Comment: The code I put in my comment is working. @mr_sudaca if you want to post this answer I will accept it!

Comment: it's ok!, glad you made it work! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in a comment by @mr_sudaca, the solution was to make the selection on an array:

```
Hash[options.to_a.select { |k, _| MY_WHITELIST.include?(k) }]
```